# How to create a log channel command?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to add a new command to my bot, a command that will send the log messages of the guild to the mentioned channel.

**Use:**

`!logs #channel`

I also want it to be a specific type of log to a different channel.

**Use:**

`!logs ban-msg #channel`

`!logs delete-msg #channel`

I don't need the second option but I do want it.

Answer (score 1):

The question asked requires a long study; Discord does not provide any simple solution. To make such functionality you need:

1. Create a database in which event data will be recorded ("_id","event","channel_id")
2. Next, you can handle [discord Events](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/WSEventType) to determine the event, then pass it through the database, see if the channel is set in the database for posting this event, if so - then send a specific embed to the specified channel.